# Rails 7 Importmap Pins incompatible Jquery source

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

### Question

Why does the source generated by the importmaps command not work with Bootstrap 4.6.1 but a modified source for the same version of jquery work?

### Problem Details

I created a rails 7 app using importmaps to manage the javascript.

I am pinning an older version of Bootstrap (4.6.1) manually in `importmap.rb`

When I run
`bin/importmap pin jquery` the following gets added to `importmap.rb`

```
pin "jquery", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.js"
```

Loading the site and looking at Chrome Web Tools displays this error message and jquery functionality such as drop-down menus and accordions do not function

```
Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
    at Object.jQueryDetection (bootstrap.min.js:6:2464)
```

However, when I update the jquery source manually in `importmap.rb` to be

```
pin "jquery", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.6.0/jquery.js"
```

the error message is resolved and functionality is restored.

To my eye the sources are almost identical, they are both jquery 3.6.0

```
https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.js
```

```
https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.6.0/jquery.js
```

### Working Configuration

`application.js`

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
Turbo.session.drive = false
import "controllers"

import  "jquery";
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
```

`importmap.rb`

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "jquery", to: "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js", preload: true
pin "bootstrap", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
pin "@popperjs/core", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@popperjs/core@2.11.2/lib/index.js"
```

Comment: base on the documentation, it says the popper should go before bootstrap:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/
"If you decide to go with the separate scripts solution, Popper must come first (if you’re using tooltips or popovers), and then our JavaScript plugins." try that, it might help

Comment: https://jasonfleetwoodboldt.com/courses/stepping-up-rails/rails-7-bootstrap/

Comment: arguably this is indeed one of the most frustrating parts of Rails 7 at this point. for this reason, I am recommending non-advanced developers stick with JSBUNDLING + CSS BUNDLING, which is significantly easier and gives you parity with webpacker on Rails 6 which is what everyone is used to. I myself have been doing Rails 15 yeras and feel the importmap stuff has just sent me down several rabbit holes costing me weeks if not months of time, so all I can say is I feel your pain.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar setup, and it works. Make jQuery available to the whole page, replace your imports at application.js by:

```
import jquery from 'jquery'
window.$ = jquery

import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
window.bootstrap = bootstrap
```

Comment: This works against the modern JS paradigm of only importing the library where you need it.

Comment: that's part of the confusion & problem -- older developers are imposing their outdated expectations on the modern paradigm without truly understanding the modern paradigm itself.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I am trying to use selectize, a jquery plugin, but even with this code above, I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'jQuery')" (not bootstrap related, but same problem).

Comment: @tkhobbes try also window.jQuery = jquery

Comment: Any suggestions on where to go to learn about "the modern JS paradigm"? Also, @springy, welcome to SO! Keep working on answering questions. You'll get the hang of it!

Comment: I switched to jsbundling in the meantime. I found importmaps too much of a hassle. But thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this, and what solved it for me was:

- With Jquery added in `importmap`
- Now, you go to the Rails configuration path "@hotwired/stimulus" to configure "jquery" in: `app/javascript/controllers/application.js`

```
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
...
import jQuery from "jquery"

window.jQuery = jQuery
window.$ = jQuery
...
```

- Just for information, in my case it looked like this:

```
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import jQuery from "jquery"

const application = Application.start()

// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus   = application
window.jQuery = jQuery
window.$ = jQuery

export { application }
```